# Sort values and output the indices of their sorted columns

Tags: sorting, unix, awk, cut

I've got a file that looks like:

```
20 30 40
80 70 60
50 30 40
```

Each column represents a procedure.  I want to know how the procedures did for each row.  My ideal output would be

```
3 2 1
1 2 3
1 3 2
```

i.e. in row 1, the third column had the highest value, followed by the second, then the first smallest (this can be reversed, doesn't matter).

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it with some other Unix tools (`read`, `cat`, `sort`, `cut`, `tr`, `sed`, and `bash` of course):

```
while read line
do
  cat -n <(echo "$line" | sed 's/ /\n/g') | sort -r -k +2 | cut -f1 | tr '\n' ' '
  echo
done < input.txt
```

The output looks like this:

```
 3      2      1 
 1      2      3 
 1      3      2
```

Comment: Is there a part of this that only requires a three-column file?  Because my actual file is considerably more than three columns.

Comment: No, that solution is general and would work with any number of columns.

Comment: Unfortunately it is giving incorrect results right now: 

0.923913 0.913043 0.880435 0.858696 0.826087 0.902174 0.836957 0.880435

gives results

1      2      6      8      3      4      7      5

Comment: It should be 1 2 4 6 8 3 7 5 (the 4 and 5 are equal and so could be switched)

Comment: Huh?  The 6th value in your list is 0.902174 which is larger than the 4th (0.858696).  So why should the result start with `1 2 4` instead of `1 2 6`??  And why do you mean that values 4 and 5 are equal?  They are 0.826087 and 0.902174.  Am I misunderstanding something basic here?

Comment: Ah, I think now I understand.  The numbers I compute denote the positions in the sorted list, but you want for each number which position it would get if it would be sorted.  Your example data did not make that clear, but what you said now does.  Let me change my answer.

Comment: Oh no, I am sorry.  This is right.  I was thinking about each column being the rank of that column's value for that row but of course that is not what I asked in my question, apologies.

Comment: No need to change it, it's perfect as is, thank you very much!

Comment: AH! Okay :)  The next task would have been interesting as well ;-)

Comment: For the other version you could use `while read line; do for i in $line; do cat -n <(echo "$line" | sed 's/ /\n/g' | sort -r -k +2) | grep "$i$" | { read a b; echo "$a"; }; done | tr '\n' ' '; echo; done`

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using Python:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jan 26 2014, 17:25:18)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.2.79)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> with open('file.txt') as f:
...    lis=[x.split() for x in f]
...
>>> for each in lis:
...     each = [i[0] + 1 for i in sorted(enumerate(each), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)]
...     print ' '.join([str(item) for item in each])
...
3 2 1
1 2 3
1 3 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Gnu Awk version 4:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc" }
{
    split($0,a," ")
    for (i in a) printf "%s%s", i,OFS
    print ""
}' file

3 2 1 
1 2 3 
1 3 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `GNU awk` then you can do something like:

```
awk '{
    y = a = x = j = i = 0;
    delete tmp;
    delete num;
    delete ind;
    for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        num[$i, i] = i
    }
    x = asorti(num)
    for(y = 1; y <= x; y++) {
        split(num[y], tmp, SUBSEP)
        ind[++j] = tmp[2]
}
for(a = x; a >= 1; a--) {
    printf "%s%s", ind[a],(a==1?"\n":" ")
}
}' file
```

```
$ cat file
20 30 40
0.923913 0.913043 0.880435 0.858696 0.826087 0.902174 0.836957 0.880435
80 70 60
50 30 40
```

```
awk '{
    y = a = x = j = i = 0;
    delete tmp;
    delete num;
    delete ind;
    for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        num[$i, i] = i
    }
    x = asorti(num)
    for(y = 1; y <= x; y++) {
        split(num[y], tmp, SUBSEP)
        ind[++j] = tmp[2]
}
for(a = x; a >= 1; a--) {
    printf "%s%s", ind[a],(a==1?"\n":" ")
}
}' file
3 2 1
1 2 6 8 3 4 7 5
1 2 3
1 3 2
```

Comment: I tried this and for the first row, which was 0.923913 0.913043 0.880435 0.858696 0.826087 0.902174 0.836957 0.880435, got 1 2 6 8 4 7 5.  Alfe's script also tried to do 12683475 which is the wrong order, this script gives the same order but the 3 has disappeared.

Comment: Aah, there are duplicate numbers across the line. `0.880435` appeared twice and hence the key was overwritten. Let me try to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution via perl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open(FH,'<','/home/chidori/input.txt') or die "Can't open file$!\n";
while(my $line=<FH>){
        chomp($line);
        my @unsorted_array=split(/\s/,$line);
        my $count=scalar @unsorted_array;
        my @sorted_array = sort { $a <=> $b } @unsorted_array;
        my %hash=map{$_ => $count--} @sorted_array;

        foreach my $value(@unsorted_array){
                print "$hash{$value} ";
        }

        print "\n";
}
```